# Deploying a web service to my Google App Engine application

Tags: iphone, python, web-services, google-app-engine

We made a simple application and using GoogleAppEngineLauncher (GAEL) ran that locally. Then we deployed, using GAEL again, to our appid. It works fine.

Now, we made a web service. We ran that locally using GAEL and a very thin local python client. It works fine.

We deployed that, and we get this message when we try to visit our default page:

"Move along people, there is nothing to see here"

We modified our local client and tried to run that against our google site and we got an error that looked like:

Response is "text/plain", not "text/xml"

Any ideas where we are falling down in our deployment or config for using a web service with google app engine?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we aren't going to get to the bottom of this one. Just not enough information available at debug time. We've managed to affect a fix on the service, although I hate ot admit it we never found out what was causing this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not setting the Content-Type header correctly in your service (assuming you ARE actually trying to send XML -- e.g. SOAP, XML-RPC, &c). What code are you using to set that header?  Without some indication about what protocol you're implementing and via what framework, it's impossible to help in detail...!